# save to django database

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

Im trying too save info to an ArrayField by using append. According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29506401) it should be possible but i cant get it to work. Im not creating a new object, it already exists i just need to append additional info to the ArrayField

Code snippet:

```
def isInDatabase(catInfo):
    cat = catagories.objects
    catName = str(catInfo)
    iban = catInfo.getIban()
    try:
        cat.get(Naam = catName)

    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        print catName, 'is not in database'
        # NOTE: create catagory
        p = cat.create(Naam = catName, Rekening = [iban])
        print catName, 'Has been stored in the database with', iban
    else:
        ibanList = cat.get(Naam = catName).Rekening
        editCat = cat.get(Naam = catName)
        print catName,'is in db, the following ibans are stored:\n\n', ibanList,'\n\n'
        if iban in ibanList:
            print iban,'is already in the list\n'
        else:
            ibanList.append(iban)
            editCat.save()
            print 'Updated list for',catName,'with -->',iban,'\nlist is now -->', ibanList,'\n'
```

the `editCat.save()` is the save command thats not saving.

models.py

```
class catagories(models.Model):
    Naam = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    Rekening = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length = 34), blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Naam
```

So what modifications do i need to make to get it to save it to the database. I don't get any error, so the script runs fine but it doesn't save to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem code:

```
ibanList = cat.get(Naam = catName).Rekening
editCat = cat.get(Naam = catName)
...
ibanList.append(iban)
editCat.save()
```

The `editCat` remains unchanged. Use call to database only once and then get `ibanList` from the object you want to edit.

```
editCat = cat.get(Naam = catName)
ibanList = editCat.Rekening
```

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize `editCat` with `editCat = cat.get(Naam = catName)`, you actually create new variable, which is not associated with `ibanList`. What you need to do is to change already retrieved value. Possible solution could be

```
editCat = cat.get(Naam = catName)
editCat.Rekening.append(iban)
editCat.save()
```

Another issue that worth to be mentioned is the presence of redundant db calls. Everytime you call `get`, you actually make new request on db (to be precise when queryset is evaluated). It would be better to retrieve value from db only once and operate over it.