# Adding to ArrayField in Django 1.10.6 with postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I'm trying to create a list in PostgreSQL of filenames and update the list on the fly.

my model(Package):

```
completed_uploads=ArrayField(models.TextField(blank=True), null=True, default=list)
```

creating the list:

```
Package.create(...,
completed_uploads = [])
```

my update code:

```
packageInstance = Package.objects.get(id=packageId)
completed_uploads = packageInstance.completed_uploads.append(request.data['filepath'])
Package.objects.filter(id=packageId).update(node = request.data['node'], completed_uploads=completed_uploads, prefix=request.data['prefix'] )
```

**edit**
I changed the above to list instead of list() --- now I get the error:

`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'` on the *second* time the function is called.  when I check my database the field 'completed_uploads' is null

Comment: Note you should use `default=list` instead of `default=list()`.

Comment: [This question was written for Django 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014966/django-1-8-arrayfield-append-extend) so might be out of date, but some of the answers might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed to change to:

```
packageInstance = Package.objects.get(id=packageId)
packageInstance.completed_uploads.append(request.data['filepath'])
Package.objects.filter(id=packageId).update(node = request.data['node'], completed_uploads=packageInstance.completed_uploads, prefix=request.data['prefix'] )
```