# how to add value in exiting list in Update Query in Django

Tags: python, django

i have model which containing a list, i want to append value in all instances from this model

```
class model(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    roles = ArrayField(base_field=models.TextField(choices=ModelRoles.choices()), default=list)
```

my update statement is

```
model.objects.all.update(roles=roles.append("new role"))
```

Comment: Do you want to update all row's in your table or you want to update specific row? From where you're getting `roles.append("new role")` please provide that too. To use `ArrayField` you've to use Postgre database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django 1.8 ArrayField append & extend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014966/django-1-8-arrayfield-append-extend)